# React Hook useEffect to fetch data from local json file to create a details page

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-hooks

I am building a detail's page to display the details of a selected object within my json file.
(click on a thumbnail image that takes you to the video page, which includes the video's details)

So far, I have 1) The data file 2) The home page where you will select the item you want to see more information off 3) The page that displays the information.

However, I have not been able to display any json data on the details page. I have tried using the "match" method, I used Request.URL(), both which did not work, but I think the right way to do it is with the useEffect hook (please correct me if I am wrong)

This is what I have at the moment with the useEffect route:

pages/FeaturedVideo.js:

```
import videos from '../../data/data.json'

const FeaturedVideo = () => {

    const [videos, setVideos] = useState(null);

     useEffect(() => {
        let url = "/src/data/data.json";
        fetch(url)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(videos => setVideos(videos))
        }, []);
    

    return(
        <div>
            <p>The video and it's details will go here </p>
            {videos.id.map((video) =>{
                <div key={video.id} {...videos}></div>
            })} 
        </div>
    )
}

export default FeaturedVideo;
```

What I am trying to do above is to use fetch to call the json file as if it were an API. And then map out the data from the specific video id.

The json file is structured in the following way:

```
[
    {   
        "id": 2,
        "firstLogo": "Minecraft",
        "thumbnail": "Thumbnail",
        "available": "Unlock 12/6",
        "sample": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c_dG_HxHMVI"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "firstLogo": "Batman",
        "thumbnail": "Thumbnail",
        "available": "Unlock 12/13",
        "sample": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c_dG_HxHMVI"
    }
]
```

The :id of the video is included into the path in the following way:

````
<Router>
      <Navbar/>
      <Switch>
          <Route path="/:videoID">
            <FeaturedVideo/>
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/">
              <Home />
          </Route>
      </Switch>
      <Footer />
    </Router>

```re
````

Comment: The res returns a promise as well you have to parse it into json with res.json() See the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: Looking at this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch i am thinking all you might have to do is add .json() to your res in your .then statement

Comment: There are a few more things there... You're mapping over video.id when you should just be mapping over the videos array of objects also you're not returning `{videos.map((video) =>{return <div key={video.id} {...videos}></div>})} `

Comment: Also your `'/'` (home path) should come before the dynamic one `'/:videoId'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of problems with this snippet:

```js
{videos.id.map((video) => {
  <div key={video.id} {...videos}></div>
})}
```

1. In your code the `videos` variable is initially `null`, and then (after fetching) — an array. Arrays don't have `id` property, and accessing properties of `null` is an illegal operation. You might want to first ensure that this is an array, rather than `null`, and then also remove the ".id" part.
2. You don't return anything from `.map()`! Yes, you create a JSX element for each item of the array, but they are destroyed unused after that.

Consider using this instead:

```js
{videos && videos.map((video) => (
  <div key={video.id} {...videos}></div>
))}
```

---

Another problem is with variables' visibility:

```js
import videos from "./path/to/data.json";
// and then later
const [ videos, setVideos ] = useState(null);
```

That first variable `videos` (the imported one) is not visible anymore, it got [shadowed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) by the second one.

You either rename the second variable to prevent shadowing, or remove the first one completely as it is unused.

---

Next thing that I can see is that the code can't make up its mind about what it is actually trying to accomplish. On one hand, router provides an ID to a specific, particular video, which means that we're trying to show only one video. On the other hand though, the `FeaturedVideo` component is almost a perfect fit for showing the list of all the videos.

Judging from the names and overall setup though, it is somewhat clear that you're trying to show one video, not the whole list.

Looks like you're using `react-router`. If that's true, in `FeaturedVideo` you need to access the video ID, provided by router. Given that it is v5+, you can use `useParams` hook for that:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router';
```

```js
const [ video, setVideo ] = useState(null); // 'video', not 'videos'
const { videoID } = useParams();

useEffect(() => {
  fetch("/src/data/data.json")
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((videos) => videos.filter((video) => {
      return video.id === videoID;
    }))
    .then((matched) => setVideo(matched[0]));
}, []);

// Here `video` variable holds either `null` or the first matched array item.
// Render it using suggestions above.
```

---

References:

- [`.map()` method of arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`&&` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND) (see **Description** section)
- [Variable shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)
- [React Router Hooks](https://dev.to/finallynero/hooks-introduced-in-react-router-v5-1-7g8)

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in using that useEffect hook. You want this data to load on component mount.

Assuming that URL returns JSON you can simply:

```
fetch(url)
  .then(res => res.json().then(videos => setVideos(videos)));
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you so so much for your reply. I tried that before and it also didn't work, but at least that is still pointing me in the right direction. I am mapping in other parts of the repo just fine, but the error I am receiving in on the line that I am using the map method. " Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions" which doesn't mean anything to me

Comment: @CarolinaKlein see my comment above, that's because you're not returning anything...